# Store 15 last values on a file on Python

Tags: python, file, list

I need to make a program that receives a integer and stores it on a file. When it has 15 (or 20, the exact number doesn't matter) it will overwrite the first one that it wrote. They may be on the same line or each one in a new line.
This program reads temperature from a sensor and then i will show that on a site with a php chart.

I thought about writing a value every half an hour maybe, and when it has 15 values and a new one comes it overwrites the oldest one.

I'm having troubles saving the values, i dont know how to save the list as a string with new lines, it saves double new lines, i'm new at python and i get really lost.

This doesn't work but it is a "sample" of what i want to do:

```
import sys
import os

if not( sys.argv[1:] ):
    print "No parameter"
    exit()

# If file doesn't exist, create it and save the value
if not os.path.isfile("tempsHistory"):
    data = open('tempsHistory', 'w+')
    data.write( ''.join( sys.argv[1:] ) + '\n' )
else:
    data = open('tempsHistory', 'a+')
    temps = []
    for line in data:
        temps += line.split('\n')
    if ( len( temps ) < 15 ):
        data.write( '\n'.join( sys.argv[1:] ) + '\n' )
    else:
        #Maximum amount reached, save new, delete oldest
        del temps[ 0 ]
        temps.append( '\n'.join( sys.argv[1:] ) )
        data.truncate( 0 )
        data.write( '\n'.join(str(e) for e in temps) )
data.close( )
```

Im getting lost with the ''.join and \n etc... I mean, i have to write with join to make the list save as a string and not with the [ '', '']. If i use '\n'.join, it saves double space, i think.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Exactly why would you want to write to a file, and then overwrite old values after 15 values? Why can't the file grow indefinitely? Perhaps whatever you try to accomplish can be solved much simpler, and better. And as suggested in an answer, this calls for a database. The built-in [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) would be ideal for this.

Comment: I'm doing this on a raspberry pi, i didn't want to save things i knew i wouldnt use. If i was going to show the last 15 intervals of 30 mins, i think i should only save 15 values! That is the main reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
import sys 

fileTemps = 'temps'

with open(fileTemps, 'rw') as fd:
    temps = fd.readlines()

if temps.__len__() >= 15:
    temps.pop(0)

temps.append(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) + '\n')

with open(fileTemps, 'w') as fd:
    for l in temps:
        fd.write(l)
```

First you open the file for reading. The fd.readlines() call will give you the lines in the file. Then you check the size, and if the number of lines is greater than 15, then you pop the first value and append the new line. Then you write everything to a file.

In Python, generally, when you read from a file (e.g. using readline()) gives you the line with an '\n' at the end, that is why you get double line breaks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really clean and works just like i want it to. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
values = open(target_file, "r").read().split("\n")
# ^ this solves your original problem as readline() will keep the \n in returned list items
if len(values) >= 15:
    # keep the values at 15
    values.pop()
values.insert(0, new_value)
# push new value at the start of the list
tmp_fd, tmp_fn = tempfile.mkstemp()
# ^ this part is important
os.write(tmp_fd, "\n".join(values))
os.close(tmp_fd)
shutil.move(tmp_fn, target_file)
# ^ as here, the operation of actual write to the file, your webserver is reading, is atomic
# this is eg. how text editors save files
```

But anyway, I'd suggest you to consider using a database, be it postgresql, redis, sqlite or whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 0):

You should try to not confuse storing data in lists with formatting in strings. Data does not require the "\n"s

So just temps.append(sys.argv[1:]) is enough.

In addition you should not serialize / deserialize the data on your own. Have a look into [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). This is much simpler to use than reading / writing lists on your own.

Comment: No. using pickle is a horrible advice. Pickle is tightly coupled to the implementation. You don't wanna use pickle unless you are gonna load the serialized thing soon, process it and forget it or so.